# Is there a vectorize way to iterate through a fixed n of an input x dict instead the full range of n?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, vectorization

Given a fixed size `n` and a `x` dict of input key-value pairs, the goal is iterate through 1...n (1st index), then fetch the values from x if the index exists as x's key, otherwise insert the value -1.

I've tried the following and it kind of work as expected:

```
n = 10  
# Valid keys ranges from [1,10], any positive integer is valid in values.
x = {1:231, 2:341, 5:123} 
y = {i+1:x[i+1] if i+1 in x else -1 for i in range(n)}
y
```

[out]:

```
{1: 231, 2: 341, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: 123, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1, 10: -1}
```

But this seems like a very common pandas or encoding / embedding operation.

**Is there a different/simpler way that can take in the sparse key-values from x and directly create y given that we know n without iterating through `O(n)` but instead `O(len(x))`?**

Rationale being, if I've billions of Xs and n is substantially huge e.g. in 1000s then the full O(n) operation is really expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) equivalent would be to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
y = pd.Series(x).reindex(range(1, n+1), fill_value=-1)
```

However I believe that trying to assign all values from the beginning is probably not the right approach. Not matter whether python or C-speed, this will be algorithmically expensive if `n` is large.

Rather use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to take advantage of "on-demand" creation of key/values in your dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
y = defaultdict(lambda : -1, x)
y[1]
# 231
y[4]
# -1
```

Or maybe:

```
n = 100
i = 50

if i < n:
    x.setdefault(i, -1)
else:
    raise ValueError(f'key {i} should be < {n}')
```

Comment: The use of `defaultdict` here is nice! Never thought of using it that way =)

Comment: @alvas and this should be the only `O(len(x))` possibility ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
y = pd.Series(x, index=range(1, n+1)).fillna(-1)
print(y)

# Output
1     231.0
2     341.0
3      -1.0
4      -1.0
5     123.0
6      -1.0
7      -1.0
8      -1.0
9      -1.0
10     -1.0
dtype: float64
```

If you prefer to use `numpy`, you can also use:

```
y = -np.ones(n)
y[np.array(list(x.keys()))-1] = list(x.values())
print(y)

# Output
[231. 341.  -1.  -1. 123.  -1.  -1.  -1.  -1.  -1.]
```

Comment: `-np.ones(n)` solution is interesting too!!